# Get Model from Generic Model

Tags: c#, generics

If I have the following method;

```
private TSource CopyFileClientModel<TSource>(TSource fileClientOrContact)
```

So into this method I can pass in either a `FileClient` or `FileContact` model.

Both have a single property called `Contact` which is also a model as well as some other properties not common between the two.

Now I want to get that `Contact` model from the passed in model.

```
Contact sourceContact = fileClientOrContact.Contact;
```

However, given this is a generic, it doesn't know that there is a `Contact` object within `TSource`.

My restriction is that I cannot place an interface against either `FileClient` or `FileContact`. I basically can't touch either of those models.

How can I get the Contact object from `TSource`?  Can I use reflection somehow?

Comment: Why `Generics`? method overload seems to be fine here.

Comment: @gdoron, i think maybe i was trying to overengineer this.  if you put the overload into an answer, i'll happily mark it

Comment: It's already an answer... see below.

Comment: ah yes.  missed that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass along a function to return the Contact.

For example:

```
private FileClient CopyFileClientModel(FileClient fileClient) {
    return this.CopyFileClientModel(fileClient, c => c.Client);
}

private FileContact CopyFileClientModel(FileContact fileContact) {
    return this.CopyFileClientModel(fileContact, c => c.Client);
}

private TSource CopyFileClientModel<TSource>(TSource fileClientOrContact, Func<TSource, Contact> contactGetter) {
    var contact = contactGetter(fileClientOrContact);
    // Whatever else...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to wrap the two classes and have the two visitor classes inherit from a common interface.

Essentially you would create a new class that has duplicate methods/properties of the `FileClient` or `FileContact` and pass an instance of the class in the constructor. All the methods and properties chain off to the actual ones in the class instance you are storing. Both of your visitor classes will have the `Contact` property, so you can tell the visitor classes to inherit from a common interface.

Comment: This seems to be a clever solution; why was there a downvote?  I would like to understand if there is an antipattern or something associated.

Comment: Downvote was because I initially suggested an interface without reading the last bit of the question. By the time I edited the answer there was a downvote.

Comment: @Skyrim, Though I didn't downvote! I think it's just too much work to do. And I think those two classes have to have the `Visit` method, don't they? The `adapter` design pattern is way better.

Comment: @RobertRouhani -- LOL; that was me, but I changed my downvote to an upvote for the new solution...that's why it went from -1 to +1 :p

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic if you use .NET 4:

```
private TSource CopyFileClientModel<TSource>(TSource fileClientOrContact)
(
    dynamic d = fileClientOrContact;

    // Now you reach the Contact property
    var x = d.Contact;
)
```

It will be wise to make validation that the `typeof(TSoruce)` is `FileClient` or `FileContact`

Another thing you can do is to wrap those two classes. see [adapter design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) in Wikipedia

---

But maybe `Generics` isn't the solution for you. Why not use Method overload with `FileClient` and `FileContact`. Your's method signature accept any TSource, But when the method get int,long, Person it's not valid, So `Generics` isn't the proper solution here if you can restrict the `TSource` to be the type you expect.

Use `Method overload` instead. and save those "creative solutions"

Comment: err, you don't want to do this, b/c `x` will be dynamic, and you know what type you are expecting for `x`!

Comment: @Skyrim, dynamic isn't bullet-proof. It's only one of the solution I suggested.

Comment: @gdoron -- lol, that's not what I meant; I offered a similar solution (at almost the same time you did ;) ), I only made the `var` into `Contact`, basically saying I'm expecting that type.

Comment: @Skyrim, I'm not sure those two Contract are the same type. maybe they only called this way. Anyway I think `Generics` here is more pain then helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Something like?

```
if (fileClientorContact is FileContact)
    return fileClientorContact as Contact;
else
    return ((Client)fileClientorContact).Contact;
```

Of course this assumes the 'Contact' in fileClientorContact is the same type you want to return. Alternatively, you could use the following if both types define a `Contact` property as you suggest in your question:

```
var propInfo = fileClientorContact.GetType().GetProperty("Contact");
if (propInfo == null)
    return false; // replace with something appropriate

return propInfo.GetValue(fileClientorClient, null, null, null) as Contact;
```

It is roughly from memory but the idea should be valid.

Comment: Yeah a little I think.  I need to get a property value from a generic model that cannot inherit an interface so the compiler won't know the property exists at design time.  and using 3.5 not 4.0

Comment: Both examples should do that (under different contexts). Is the name of the property that returns the object your looking for not named "Contact"? Do you know the name of the property that should be used or do you need to determine it too at runtime?

Comment: no, i know the name of the propert which also happens to be an object

Comment: @griegs - If nothing else my second example should roughly show you how to accomplish this at runtime with Reflection.

Comment: Edited idiotic mistakes caused by it being *way* too late. Hopefully it will be considered more appropriate now.

Comment: +1 for the answer.  Didn't implement it but still a relevant method thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using C# 4.0 you can use dynamics

```
 dyanmic obj = fileClientOrContact;
 Contact sourceContact = obj.Contact;
```

This is not ideal, though! (it can cause runtime exceptions)

---

**EDIT**

Alternatively, I would probably go with two overload functions for each type, with each function calling a common function for shared functionality.

Comment: No, that would have been really nice, but no.

Comment: @griegs -- why would this not work? by the way `dyanamic` should `dynamic`.  I just tested it out on my compiler.

Comment: :) no probs.  kinda sucks when you are restricted and you know you can do it better using up-to-date tech +1 though

Answer (score 0):

If `FileContact` and `FileClient` share no ancestors that have `.Contact`, and you are unable to implement a common interface for it, and you really want to use reflection, then you could do something like this:

```
    var sourceProp = typeof(TSource).GetProperty("Source");
    Contact contact;
    if(sourceProp != null)
    {
        contact = (Contact)sourceProp.getValue(fileClientOrContact, null)
    }
```